# Call a function after react-redux dispatch has finished

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

So I have here a form which which when submitted, calls this function:

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      dispatch(addCategory({ category, identifier, definition }));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
```

and this is the code to my `addCategory` action in a separate file.

```
export const addCategory =
  ({ category, identifier, definition }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/Admin/addCategory",
        { category, identifier, definition }
      );

      dispatch({ type: "ADD_CATEG", payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: "GET_ERROR",
        payload: error.response.data.errorMessage,
      });
    }
  };
```

As you can see, I have an error handling in my backend and it triggers when the user inputs a duplicate data. The way I am getting that error is through this:

```
const { error } = useSelector((state) => state.categories);
```

What I want is that after I dispatch my action in my `handleSubmit`, it checks whether the error is empty or not. I've tried to call a function after the try-catch block in `handleSubmit` which looks like this. I've tried to run it then I've entered correct inputs of data without error, it displays 'no err' but if I tried to enter a duplicate input, it doesn't give me an error but in my redux console, it is already there. When I submit the form again, then it will now display the 'with err'. I've been trying to figure it out but can't seem to find any solutions.

```
const try = () => {
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log("with err");
    } else if (error === null) {
      console.log("no err");
    }
  };
```

Comment: You can await dispatch when dispatching an async thunk. But if you are doing that it would probably make more sense to get the error from the returned action than from the state.  const action = await dispatch(…

Comment: @Linda Paiste I'm sorry but I can barely understand it. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem as well.

- One is catching an error on the request being sent
- The other is catching an error from data handling on the Redux side

  This is a pattern I've used before, you just need to make sure you are handling errors at every level.

  ```
  export const addCategory =
      ({ category, identifier, definition }) =>
      async (dispatch) => {
        let response
        try {
          response = await axios.post(
            "http://localhost:5000/Admin/addCategory",
            { category, identifier, definition }
          );

          dispatch({ type: "ADD_CATEG", payload: data });
        } catch (error) {
         response = 
          dispatch({
            type: "GET_ERROR",
            payload: error.response.data.errorMessage,
          });
        }
        if(response?.data){
          // do stuff for success
         }
        // do stuff for errors
      };
  ```

Comment: I've tried the code you provided but it's not working. I've also tried using async/await in my submit and still not working. Can you figure why?

Comment: put a debugger/log in the `if(response?.data)` block and see what it's returning.

Comment: Also, getting an error then dispatching to get that type of error is a bit...different. Your error coming back should contain the info you need to handle it.